# Bind many keys at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I've noticed that i was quickly stuck when i wanted to do a game which needed simultaneous key presses on Tkinter. That's why i decided to create a widget which allow the user to get all active keys.

The methode is simple:

- I've a set
- When a key is pressed, I add it into the set
- When a key is released, I discard from the set
- If the user want to know which keys are pressed, I just return the set

I've done this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Tk_Multikey(tk.Frame):
    """Allow the user to get all actived keys"""

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.keysym = set()
        self.keycode = set()
        self.keysym_num = set()
        master.bind('<KeyPress>', self.add_a_key, add='+')
        master.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.discard_a_key, add='+')

    def add_a_key(self, event):
        """When a key is pressed, add its keysym, keycode and keysym_num to the corresponding set"""

        self.keysym.add(event.keysym.upper()) # the upper method prevents a 
        # bug when the user is using the Shift/Caplock key and a letter key
        self.keycode.add(event.keycode)
        self.keysym_num.add(event.keysym_num)


    def discard_a_key(self, event):
        """When a key is released, discard its keysym, keycode and keysym_num to the corresponding set"""

        self.keysym.discard(event.keysym.upper()) 
        self.keycode.discard(event.keycode)
        self.keysym_num.discard(event.keysym_num)


    def __delattr__(self, nameattr):
        """The user is not allowed to delete a set"""
        raise AttributeError("Unable to delete")

    def get_keys(self):
        return((self.keysym, self.keycode, self.keysym_num))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def update(event=None):
        print("updating")
        strvar_keysym.set(mtk.keysym)
        strvar_keycode.set(mtk.keycode)
        strvar_keysym_num.set(mtk.keysym_num)

    root = tk.Tk()

    mtk = Tk_Multikey(root)
    mtk.pack()

    root.bind('<KeyPress>', update, add='+')
    root.bind('<KeyRelease>', update, add='+')

    strvar_keysym = tk.StringVar()
    strvar_keycode = tk.StringVar()
    strvar_keysym_num = tk.StringVar()
    update()

    tk.Label(root, textvariable=strvar_keysym).pack()    
    tk.Label(root, textvariable=strvar_keycode).pack()    
    tk.Label(root, textvariable=strvar_keysym_num).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Now I have a bug that i don't understand.

When I press A, Z, E, R, that works; But if I press A, Z, E, R T, that doesn't work (the T does not appear). However, if i only press A, Z, E, T, that works. I believed that the maximum was 4 but i've tried with many other key and it's not that. (I've the same bug with W, X, C for exemple)

Why this bug happens and what can i do to solve it?

Thank you :)

PS: I don't know why i can't say hello at the beginning of my message.. So i put it a the end: Hello there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses).
Specifically [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) Wikipedia page under n-key rollover.

Basically, your keyboard cannot take a certain amount of keys because they communicate on the same circuit. It is a hardware limitation. Try mapping out different key combinations to see which ones work together and which don't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you're right. I've tested some combinaisons which are not suppose to work (according to your wikpedia page) and.. That doesn't work.

Ok so, that was just that. ^^ Thanks for all. Problem solved :)